# Slick: How to filter by isBefore Timestamp database attribute?

Tags: scala, jodatime, slick

I naively did the following on Slick 4.0.1. I have an expiry database field and I need to find all the rows where the expiry is before a given timestamp.

This is what the Slick mapping looks like:

```
/** Table description of table auth_token. Objects of this class serve as prototypes for rows in queries. */
class AuthToken(_tableTag: Tag) extends profile.api.Table[AuthTokenRow](_tableTag, Some("myappdb"), "auth_token") with IdentifyableTable[Long] {
  override def id = userId

  def * = (userId, tokenId, expiry) <> (AuthTokenRow.tupled, AuthTokenRow.unapply)
  /** Maps whole row to an option. Useful for outer joins. */
  def ? = ((Rep.Some(userId), Rep.Some(tokenId), Rep.Some(expiry))).shaped.<>({ r => import r._; _1.map(_ => AuthTokenRow.tupled((_1.get, _2.get, _3.get))) }, (_: Any) => throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

  /** Database column user_id SqlType(BIGINT UNSIGNED) */
  val userId: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("user_id")
  /** Database column token_id SqlType(CHAR), Length(36,false) */
  val tokenId: Rep[String] = column[String]("token_id", O.Length(36, varying = false))
  /** Database column expiry SqlType(TIMESTAMP) */
  val expiry: Rep[java.sql.Timestamp] = column[java.sql.Timestamp]("expiry")

  /** Foreign key referencing User (database name auth_token_ibfk_1) */
  lazy val userFk = foreignKey("auth_token_ibfk_1", userId, User)(r => r.id, onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.NoAction, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)

  /** Index over (tokenId) (database name idx_token_id) */
  val index1 = index("idx_token_id", tokenId)
}
/** Collection-like TableQuery object for table AuthToken */
lazy val AuthToken = new TableQuery(tag => new AuthToken(tag))
```

and then I need to do:

```
/**
 * Finds expired tokens.
 *
 * @param dateTime The current date time.
 */
def findExpired(dateTime: org.joda.time.DateTime): Future[Seq[AuthTokenRow]] = {
  val action = AuthToken.filter(authToken => authToken.expiry.isBefore(dateTime)).result
  db.run(action)
}
```

How to cover this use-case correctly/officially in Slick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by reusing the project [slick-joda-mapper](https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper). This solution is a bit involved because of working with the Slick generator etc but it is VERY clean, I love it. Basically it enables mapping database date time types to the Joda types like `org.joda.time.DateTime`. Therefore my solution becomes as simple as using comparison operators supported by Joda DateTime:

```
/**
 * Finds expired tokens.
 *
 * @param dateTime The current date time.
 */
override def findExpired(dateTime: org.joda.time.DateTime): Future[Seq[AuthTokenRow]] = {
  val action = AuthToken.filter(authToken => authToken.expiry < dateTime).result
  db.run(action)
}
```